# Manually Triggering Form Validation using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, validation

I have a form with several different fieldsets. I have some jQuery that displays the field sets to the users one at a time. For browsers that support HTML5 validation, I'd love to make use of it. However, I need to do it on my terms. I'm using JQuery.

When a user clicks a JS Link to move to the next fieldset, I need the validation to happen on the current fieldset and block the user from moving forward if there is issues.

Ideally, as the user loses focus on an element, validation will occur.

Currently have novalidate going and using jQuery. Would prefer to use the native method. :)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

<strike>You can't trigger the native validation UI</strike> (see edit below), but you can easily take advantage of the validation API on arbitrary input elements:

```
$('input').blur(function(event) {
    event.target.checkValidity();
}).bind('invalid', function(event) {
    setTimeout(function() { $(event.target).focus();}, 50);
});
```

The first event fires `checkValidity` on every input element as soon as it loses focus, if the element is `invalid` then the corresponding event will be fired and trapped by the second event handler.  This one sets the focus back to the element, but that could be quite annoying, I assume you have a better solution for notifying about the errors.  [Here's a working example of my code above](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/4Hk9G/).

**EDIT:** All modern browsers [support](https://caniuse.com/constraint-validation) the [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) method for native HTML5 validation, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267035/4404971).

Comment: Golden sentence **"You can't trigger the native validation UI"**. In my case (custom JS tricks + Browser html5 validation + UI tooltips) I had no choice than go for hidden submit button at the end to get both

Comment: If your form doesn't have a submit button, you can fake one: `$('<input type="submit">').hide().appendTo($myForm).click().remove();`

Comment: @philfreo Wouldn't a `form.submit()` work just fine? Or does HTML5 require a submit button for the validation now?

Comment: @Mattisdada Calling `.submit()` does not work for me. @philfreo's solution works. Hmm.

Comment: Just a reminder that `checkValidity` only checks it, but **does not popup the browser's standard hint**. If you want the popup too - use `element.reportValidity()`

Comment: is there still no way to trigger native validation UI (i.e. causing one the inputs to be viewed as "invalid" by the browser)?

Comment: @Alex i thought this would be what i was looking for. what i am doing is validating the user input against a massive array of values in JS; if the array does not contain the value, then id like to trigger the `invalid` event for that input element, in turn triggering the native invalid UI. is this somehow possible to do using `reportValidity()`?

Comment: The only issue of this solution is if we have more than one required field of this form then the autofocus will have an infinite loop since validation triggers when focus leaves from an input

Answer (score 229):

**TL;DR:** Not caring about old browsers? Use [`form.reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity).

Need legacy browser support? Read on.

---

It actually *is* possible to trigger validation manually.

I'll use plain JavaScript in my answer to improve reusability, no jQuery is needed.

---

Assume the following HTML form:

```
<form>
  <input required>
  <button type="button">Trigger validation</button>
</form>
```

And let's grab our UI elements in JavaScript:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
var triggerButton = document.querySelector('button')
```

---

**Don't need support for legacy browsers like Internet Explorer? This is for you.**

All modern browsers [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=constraint-validation) the [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) method on `form` elements.

```
triggerButton.onclick = function () {
    form.reportValidity()
}
```

That's it, we're done. Also, [here's a simple CodePen](https://codepen.io/loilo/pen/YOgKMw?editors=1010) using this approach.

---

**Approach for older browsers**

> Below is a detailed explanation how `reportValidity()` can be emulated in older browsers.
>
> However, you don't need to copy&paste those code blocks into your project yourself — there is a [ponyfill](https://github.com/jelmerdemaat/report-validity)/[polyfill](https://gist.github.com/nuxodin/73a2c2423cbbf6818c28ad803985d5c7) readily available for you.

Where `reportValidity()` is not supported, we need to trick the browser a little bit. So, what will we do?

1. Check validity of the form by calling `form.checkValidity()`. This will tell us if the form is valid, but not show the validation UI.
2. If the form is invalid, we create a temporary submit button and trigger a click on it. Since the form is not valid, we *know* it won't *actually* submit, however, it will show validation hints to the user. We'll remove the temporary submit button immedtiately, so it will never be visible to the user.
3. If the form is valid, we don't need to interfere at all and let the user proceed.

---

In code:

```
triggerButton.onclick = function () {
  // Form is invalid!
  if (!form.checkValidity()) {
    // Create the temporary button, click and remove it
    var tmpSubmit = document.createElement('button')
    form.appendChild(tmpSubmit)
    tmpSubmit.click()
    form.removeChild(tmpSubmit)

  } else {
    // Form is valid, let the user proceed or do whatever we need to
  }
}
```

This code will work in pretty much any common browser (I've tested it successfully down to IE11).

[Here's a working CodePen example.](https://codepen.io/loilo/pen/YYjbgE?editors=1010)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2021.

Comment: That answer is obviously perfect :)

Comment: Not sure how old would be *"old browsers"*. https://caniuse.com/constraint-validation. I guess you could call them legacy browsers now :P

Comment: jQuery Example:  $('#myFormId')..get(0).reportValidity();

Answer (score 23):

In some extent, You CAN `trigger` HTML5 form validation and show hints to user without submitting the form!

Two button, one for validate, one for submit

Set a `onclick` listener on the validate button to set a global flag(say `justValidate`) to indicate this click is intended to check the validation of the form.

And set a `onclick` listener on the submit button to set the `justValidate` flag to false.

Then in the `onsubmit` handler of the form, you check the flag `justValidate` to decide the returning value and invoke the `preventDefault()` to stop the form to submit. As you know, the HTML5 form validation(and the GUI hint to user) is preformed before the `onsubmit` event, and even if the form is VALID you can stop the form submit by returning false or invoke `preventDefault()`.

And, in HTML5 you have a method to check the form's validation: the `form.checkValidity()`, then in you can know if the form is validate or not in your code.

OK, here is the demo:
http://jsbin.com/buvuku/2/edit

Answer (score 3):

```js
var field = $("#field")
field.keyup(function(ev){
    if(field[0].value.length < 10) {
        field[0].setCustomValidity("characters less than 10")
        
    }else if (field[0].value.length === 10) {
        field[0].setCustomValidity("characters equal to 10")
        
    }else if (field[0].value.length > 10 && field[0].value.length < 20) {
        field[0].setCustomValidity("characters greater than 10 and less than 20")
        
    }else if(field[0].validity.typeMismatch) {
     field[0].setCustomValidity("wrong email message")
        
    }else {
     field[0].setCustomValidity("") // no more errors
        
    }
    field[0].reportValidity()
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" id="field">
```

Comment: Would you add more explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat easy to make add or remove HTML5 validation to fieldsets.

```
 $('form').each(function(){

    // CLEAR OUT ALL THE HTML5 REQUIRED ATTRS
    $(this).find('.required').attr('required', false);

    // ADD THEM BACK TO THE CURRENT FIELDSET
    // I'M JUST USING A CLASS TO IDENTIFY REQUIRED FIELDS
    $(this).find('fieldset.current .required').attr('required', true);

    $(this).submit(function(){

        var current     = $(this).find('fieldset.current')
        var next        = $(current).next()

        // MOVE THE CURRENT MARKER
        $(current).removeClass('current');
        $(next).addClass('current');

        // ADD THE REQUIRED TAGS TO THE NEXT PART
        // NO NEED TO REMOVE THE OLD ONES
        // SINCE THEY SHOULD BE FILLED OUT CORRECTLY
        $(next).find('.required').attr('required', true);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I seem to find the trick:
Just remove the form `target` attribute, then use a submit button to validate the form and show hints, check if form valid via JavaScript, and then post whatever. The following code works for me:

```
<form>
  <input name="foo" required>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

```
<script>
$('#submit').click( function(e){
  var isValid = true;
  $('form input').map(function() {
    isValid &= this.validity['valid'] ;
  }) ;
  if (isValid) {
    console.log('valid!');
    // post something..
  } else
    console.log('not valid!');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's the real solution for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Html Code:

```
<form class="validateDontSubmit">
....
<button style="dislay:none">submit</button>
</form>
<button class="outside"></button>
```

javascript( using Jquery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('submit','.validateDontSubmit',function (e) {
    //prevent the form from doing a submit
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
})

$(document).ready(function(){
// using button outside trigger click
    $('.outside').click(function() {
        $('.validateDontSubmit button').trigger('click');
    });
});
</script>
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: Why is it answering the question ?

Comment: it using HTML5 validate without submit.
and use Form data for your purpose: form_data =  $('.validateDontSubmit').serializeArray();

Answer (score 1):

For input field

```html
<input id="PrimaryPhNumber" type="text" name="mobile"  required
                                       pattern="^[789]\d{9}$" minlenght="10" maxLength="10" placeholder="Eg: 9444400000"
                                       class="inputBoxCss"/>
```

```js
$('#PrimaryPhNumber').keyup(function (e) {
        console.log(e)
        let field=$(this)
        if(Number(field.val()).toString()=="NaN"){
            field.val('');
            field.focus();
            field[0].setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid phone number');
            field[0].reportValidity()
            $(":focus").css("border", "2px solid red");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id').get(0).reportValidity();
```

This will trigger the input with ID specified. Use ".classname" for classes.

Answer (score 1):

you might want to know that this function reportValidity() always returns a boolean value. You should also know that it's a native JS function so you shouldn't call using jQuery.

So we can do something like this example bellow:

```
<script>
if (document.getElementById('frmUser').reportValidity()) { 
    $('#frmUser').submit();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

When there is a very complex (especially asynchronous) validation process, there is a simple workaround:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:submitIfVeryComplexValidationIsOk()" />
<input type="submit" id="form1_submit_hidden" style="display:none" />
</form>
...
<script>
function submitIfVeryComplexValidationIsOk() {
    var form1 = document.forms['form1']
    if (!form1.checkValidity()) {
        $("#form1_submit_hidden").click()
        return
    }

    if (checkForVeryComplexValidation() === 'Ok') {
         form1.submit()
    } else {
         alert('form is invalid')
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Another way to resolve this problem:

```
$('input').oninvalid(function (event, errorMessage) {
    event.target.focus();
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I get: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).oninvalid is not a function` and I do not see it in the jQuery docs.

Comment: I think it should be saying "invalid" and not "oninvalid" as you are using jQuery here.