# Display HTML5 client-side validation error bubbles after event.preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, validation

After invalidate the default behaviour of the form I would like to display HTML5 client-side validation error bubbles.

I did try the following code but it does not work.

Any ideas?

```
validateForm: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // some code
    console.log(this.$el.find('form')[0]); // it display the form I would like to validate
    this.$el.find('form')[0].checkValidity();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried returning `false`?

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` ??

Comment: I tried return false it does not work.

Comment: @Val using `event.stopPropagation();` I don't need to use checkValidity because the error bubbles is showed. but should I use `event.stopPropagation` instead of `preventDefault` what is the difference in submitting a form?

Comment: @Val I used event.stopPropagation and it submits a form reloading the page. but I don't want this behaviour. so I have to use preventDefault.

Comment: Have you tried em' all at once? like `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault(); return false;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triggering HTML5 Form Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation)

Answer (score 2):

Your code about validateForm can be improved in this way:

```
validateForm: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // some code
    event.currentTarget.checkValidity();
});
```

If it does not work the issue will be about how you call validateForm function.

If you are in a `Backbone.View`, as I suppose since you are using "this.$el", you should write the events object simply in this way:

```
events: {
    'submit form': 'validateForm'
    // 'click button': 'validateForm' // this way does not work
}
```