# jQuery HTML5 input valid live

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, pattern-matching

**I have an input field that looks like this:**

```
<input type="number" id="month" placeholder="Month" min="1" max="12" required>
```

**Problem**

- When I use it in a form it requires a number to be between 1 and 12.
- I use jQuery to copy the information with keyup, in my case to a href. In this case it's not "protected" by any requirements in the field.

**Example**

Should not be valid:

```
<a href="?month=abc">
```

Should be valid:

```
<a href="?month=12">
```

Can I use the validation from the built in HTML5 input somehow? I have different fields with different requirements.

Comment: When you copy the value you can validate it there.  Show us the script you have for doing that.

Comment: If you really want to hook into the validation, there's this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation/7562439#7562439

Answer (score 0):

When you are capturing the value on the `keyup` you can use the `isNaN` function to check if it's a number or not. This will validate decimals though as well, so you'll want to check that there's no decimal.

```
if (!isNaN(someValue)){
   //your code to add to href
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All i got from your question is that you want to validate `<a>` tag from jquery

```
$("a[href*='month']").click(function(event){
    var value=$(this).attr("href");
    value=value.split("=");
    var temp=value[1];
    alert(temp);
    if(isNaN(temp)){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("not a number");
    }
    else if(temp<1||temp>12){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("invalid month");
    }
});
```

**EDIT:** 
thanks to jack's comment, here is the possible solution of question asked

```
$("#month").keyup(function(){
    //Add your copying code here, and edit $atag accordingly 
    var $atag=$("a[href*='month']");
    var value=$(this).val();
    if(isNaN(value)){
        $atag.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else if(value<1||value>12){
        $atag.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
    else $atag.removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to validate the input is a number before he appends it to the href.

Comment: as he stated in question that <a href="?month=abc"> should not be valid, so i done in that way

Comment: `I use jQuery to copy the information with keyup, in my case to a href.` He's taking the value of the input on keyup then assigning it to the href. He can do all evaluation in the keyup.

Comment: @Jack i edited my solution, i hope this is what u were referring

Comment: An anchor has no disabled attribute. Why do you write if else if else for only two different actions. A simple if else would do the same. Where are you using the HTML5 API?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use the HTML5 form validation API. But this requires, that the browser supports this API or you are using a polyfill. Currently FF4+, IE10+, Chrome and Safari do support the API. But FF does not fully support the number type.

If you want to use the HTML5-API:

1. use the input event instead of the keyup event. This is much better event for your task (think, paste, cut and so on).
2. Simply use the :valid Selector to test, wether input is valid (if not polyfilled, will throw an error in IE9-)

I have put together a [simple solution for you](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/UDR3n/), which is using webshims to polyfill the API for you.

But to be honest, I question your approach. You can simply use a form with a button, proper action attribute and a month named type="number" instead of a link + JS for your solution and do not need to add JS at all. Code could look like this and you get the HTML form validation for free:

```
<form action="#">
    <div>
        <button class="text" type="submit">to month: </button> 
        <input type="number" name="month" placeholder="Month" min="1" max="12" required value="1" size="2" />
    </div>
</form>
```

My example also shows how to style a button as a link.