# Javascript/jQuery validate email like the browser does

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I know it is possibly to use the default browser validation for forms, when making custom form `submit`:

```
event.target.checkValidity();
```

That does the trick.

However now, I want to validate an email that is not in the form yet, and check whether it is an email or not. I prefer not to use regex, but use the in-built browser validation, just like it does with `event.target.checkValidity()`.

Any clue how I can call the function that `checkValidity()` uses underlying to check whether an email is correct or not?

Comment: Is this any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation

Comment: @LauriElias Sadly not, I want the result of the `event.target.checkValidity()`, I don't want it to throw custom error messages at the screen or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a dynamic element and use its `checkValidity` method?

```
function isEmailValid(emailAddress) {
    var email = document.createElement("input");
    email.type = "email";
    email.value = emailAddress;
    return email.checkValidity();
}
console.log(isEmailValid("test@email.com"));
```

[Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/44ZqW/).

Or if you want to test an existing input element:

```
function isInputValid(input) {
    return input && input.checkValidity && input.checkValidity();
}
console.log(isInputValid(document.getElementById("userEmail")));
```

It's worth noting that `checkValidity()` returns true for an empty e-mail address. So if you need it to be non-empty, you'll need to check that yourself.

Comment: Does that only work on `:input` elements, and not on strings?

Comment: Added a demo to show how it works. `emailAddress` should be a string parameter.

Comment: +1. What would complete this, would be combining those two methods. Add a control statement to check the arguments type and voila... one method to rule all email validation. Be it a string, or input. I think I'll pinch your examples for future use :)

Comment: I can't seem to get it work for jQuery input elements though. `.checkValidity` gives a `TypeError` and `.checkValidity()` returns `undefined`. I think you need to use the proto part if that's the case? Not sure how it works there though.

Comment: @skiwi It needs an HTML element. So to get that from jQuery you can use .get(): `isInputValid($("#emailInput").get());`