# Can you add a name to your link in an URL input field?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I hope I explain this in a way that makes sense.

You have an url input field.

```
<input id="myURL" name="myURL" type="url">
```

If you enter a url into this, eg [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com),
then it will output "www.stackoverflow.com" on the page.

But what if I don't want it to show the url, but instead show "Click here"?

I know this can easily be done with a tags, but how do you do this with input fields?

I read this guide on MDN Web Docs
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/url
but it does not provide me with any information regarding that issue.

Answer (score 0):

No.

URL fields are designed for entering URLs, not generating HTML links consisting of a URL and display text.

If you want to input display text as well, use a seperate text input.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something line this?

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const url = new URL(this.myURL.value); // possibly a bit overkill but it validates and allows adding parameters
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = `<a href="${url.toString()}" taget="_blank">Click here</a>`;
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input id="myURL" name="myURL" type="url">
</form>
<hr/>
<span id="res"></span>
```

or this

```js
const form = document.getElementById("myForm")
form.addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const url = new URL(this.myURL.value); // possibly a bit overkill but it validates and allows adding parameters
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = `<a href="${url.toString()}" taget="_blank">Click here</a>`;
  form.hidden = true;
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input id="myURL" name="myURL" type="url">
</form>
<span id="res"></span>
```

Comment: sorry for disturbing i have a question and i will like you to help me with  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66567366/form-not-sending-data-after-submitting-in-some-device-mostly-iphones