# Input validation for text boxes in HTML5

Tags: html

I have a form like this,

```
<form>
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="button" value="Post">
</form>
```

I want a tooltip to pop-up if the user clicks on the button without entering anything in the textbox.

I know it will work if I change the button to like this - `<input type="submit" value="Post">`. But I don't want to do that.

Comment: How do you submit the form without a submit button?

Comment: @GjermundDahl I don't want to submit the form. When the button is clicked, some javascript function will get triggered. But if the button is clicked with no text in the textbox, a tooltip should show up. Is that possible?

Comment: The only way to display the native error message that some browser have, is by submit. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866910/how-to-force-a-html5-form-validation-without-submitting-it-via-jquery

Comment: @GjermundDahl - I figured out how to do this based an answer from this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation See my answer below - maybe it helps someone else too!

Comment: So you do submit the form :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean `formaction` instead of `action`?

```
<input type="text" name="usrname" required formaction="action_page.php">
```

`action` is a `form` tag attribute, not `input`s's.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5

Try like this it will work :
action attribute specifically for `form` tag. not `input` tag

```
<form action="action_page.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required >
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use method "POST" in  tag, It will work

```
   <form action="action_page.php" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required >
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this with some jQuery based on an answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation) post.

The following code does exactly what I was looking for,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required id="input">
  <input type="button" value="Post" id="button">
</form>


<script>
$('#button').click(function(e) {

  if ($('#input').val() === "") {

      $('<input type="submit">').hide().appendTo('#myForm').click().remove();

  }

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/yehuwajalo/edit?html,output) for DEMO