# Strict number input field

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input

I have a simple input field with type set to number. This will be used to enter input in [0,255] range (for RGB).

```
<input type="number" id="inputBox" min="0" max="255" step="1" />
```

In its current form, this input field will accept the following values:

```
012   // zero prefixed numbers
1.0   // floating-point
.1    // floating-point
-5    // range underflow
300   // range overflow
```

I want it to accept only the integers in the range of [0,255]. So, no zero prefix, no floating-point numbers.

I've solved the range problem using `input` event:

```
inputBox.addEventListener("input", function () {
    if (this.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
        this.value = this.min;
    }
    else if (this.validity.rangeOverflow) {
        this.value = this.max;
    }
});
```

and floating-point problem using `keydown` event (by not allowing `.`):

```
inputBox.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (!isFloat(this.step)) {
        if (e.key == ".") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});

function isFloat(f) {
    var f        = parseFloat(f);
    var floor    = Math.floor(f);
    var fraction = f - floor;
    if (fraction > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm stuck at solving the zero prefixed numbers problem. I can use the following line of code in the `input` event to remove zero prefix

```
this.value = this.valueAsNumber; // or parseInt(this.value, 10)
```

which is working fine, but this kind of breaks the input field's functionality. I can't enter values with `E` notation. In my case, I don't need to, but I might somewhere else. As soon as I enter `1e`, it evaluates to `NaN`, and is assigned back to input field.

Is there a way to make these both work?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/1cwf8tbr/)

Comment: All requirements except the zero prefixed numbers can be obtain with `<input type="number" step="1" />`

Comment: Why do you need 1e? Sounds to me, like two separate issues. You need 1 input that only allows 0-255 and another that supports `1e`. However, I don't think you would ever want an RGB input to accept something like `1e`, right?

Comment: @KevBot If I want to use this functionality in another project which I need to use exponential values, I'll face this problem again. So why ignore it now?

Comment: Because you wouldn't want to accept `1e` in an an RGB value which seems to be what this question is about. They are two separate things.

Comment: I need a solution that respects the min and max values. This is simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just worked on a problem like this. It's super easy to do:

```
inputBox.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (!isFloat(this.step)) {
        if (e.key == ".") {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    while ( this.value.toString()[0] === "0" && this.value.length > 0){
       this.value = this.value.toString().slice(1);
    }

});
```

Note that the value of the field might change in ways other than `keydown` events, suck as `paste`. So I would put these checks in a function, `validationCheck`, and run that function for each relevant event, including the catchall- `onchange`.

Comment: There might be multiple zeros in the beginning. That will require further checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression such as:

```
<input type="text" pattern="0|[1-9]\d*">
```

this will gives you a string representation of a positive whole number without prefixed zeros.
You then have to test with JavaScript if the value is less than or equals 255.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8NrE/2568/).
String with only multiple zeros are not accepted.

Comment: I can still add multiple zeros. I've added a jsfiddle. You can test it.

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I'm not using a form. I'm not sending any data to a server. This is a client application. The data entered to the field is used in real-time.

Comment: This doesn't matter, the validation is done by the browser. You can use it locally.

Comment: No, what I mean is I don't have a submit button. The validation should happen as I enter the value.

Comment: If needed you can have an hidden submit button to trigger the validation. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation