# Make native HTML validation trigger after a jQuery-induced form submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to bind some manual validation to the `on('submit')` event in jQuery after pausing the submission, but have it **still perform the browser's native HTML validation**. However, I cannot get it to work.

This is my bare-bones code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prevent Form Submission</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="example" required>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            // Do something here
            $('form').submit();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this code, I can prevent the form from submitting, but then when I run the `submit()` event it "skips" the HTML validation and just submits, even if the required field is empty. I am using Google Chrome Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit).

If I change the jQuery to this:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something here
    $(this).submit();
});
```

I cannot even get it to submit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation

Comment: You have to think that every browser will show the HTML validation in different ways, so perhaps it's more interesting to make the validation yourself by JQuery. Anyway, the answer from CBroe  seems correct.

Comment: So nobody knows when the actual HTML validation happens? i.e. on which event, so we can work around it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by using Javascript's native `this` as opposed to jQuery's `$(this)`.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do something
    form.submit();
});
```