# How do I trigger the required alert for Input elements on lose focus

Tags: html

My HTMl form has an email input with a required attribute:

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
```

On form submit, an alert is displayed when the user does not enter the correct format.

Is there a way that when the input loses focus, the alert is still triggered when the user does not follow the correct format?

Comment: You may can trigger the form submission or implement your own validation method..

Comment: Using JavaScript I suppose? I'll give it a try

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7548612/863110) may will help you.

Comment: Yes, that is very much helpful. Much obliged :-)

Comment: My pleasure :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On Vanilla JavaScript, I used the checkValidity() and validationMessage on the DOM. Here is the code:

```
email.addEventListener("blur", function(){
        if(!email.checkValidity()){
            document.getElementById("errEmail").innerHTML = email.validationMessage;
        }
})
```