# Required function is not working in HTML form

Tags: html, required

I already apply `<Required>` tag in HTML `<Select>` but not working. The form is still able to proceed to the next step even not select anything at first step. Anyone know to solve it?

```html
    <label>Region :</label>
    <select id="Region" class="custom-select form-control" required>
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
    <option value="central" id="Central">Central</option>
    <option value="northern" id="Northern">Northern</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I expect this is due to `Select Region` being selected by default because it has a non-value.  As far as the form is concerned it is a valid option and therefore the `required` indicator has been satisfied

Comment: So how to make the selection is deselect by default? Any idea? :-)

Comment: I suggest you use form validation and Javascript to validate the input before it's submitted. Like Martin says above, the 'required' indicator is satisfied when 'Select Region' is selected by default.

Comment: Maybe you could replace the "Select Region" with a label instead of giving it no value as Martin says it auto-satisfies by default.

Comment: do you mean like this? `<option value=""><label>Select Region</label></option>`

Comment: @craig1231 I will try later. :-)

Comment: No, I mean putting the label on top of the dropdown, like a header telling the user what the dropdown is about.

Comment: Technical nit-pcik, there is no required **tag** it is an **attribute**

Comment: Your code works.... at least in chrome : https://jsfiddle.net/y4j6rmdL/ . Have you tested in multiple browsers? Is it browser specific? Note you **need** `form` tag as the `required` attribute pertains to **form validation**

Comment: ... however you can still get CSS working without the `form` tag : https://jsfiddle.net/y4j6rmdL/ . Basically we need more information from you. Create a [mcve] that adequately demonstrates the problem. Is this purely a javascript construct? Is the form actually submitted or is this more a multi-step form.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267035/4665) may also be of interest to you

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your web page using HTML5? Make sure you declare the following statement at the beginning of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

The `required` attribute is only available in HTML5 and only supported by specific browsers... [w3schools Required Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Having tested your original code in HTML5, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of the select option tag entirely, and place the value `select option` in the select tag itself.

```
<label>Region:</label>
<select value="Select Option" id="Region" class="custom-select form- control" required>

<option value="central" id="Central">Central</option>
<option value="northern" id="Northern">Northern</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I also have tried `<option disable>Select Region</option>` but the `Select Region` is still selected by default.

Comment: Are you able to to make it a label instead of putting it into the dropdown? Would that be good? Because it seems pointless to worry about something that small when you could just prompt the user via a label. Not to be critical.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works it depends on the browser you use or the way that you are using it. I wrote a sample code for you. Hope it may help you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form >
 <label>Region :</label>
    <select id="Region" class="custom-select form-control" required>
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
    <option value="central" id="Central">Central</option>
    <option value="northern" id="Northern">Northern</option>
    </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

So in the code above if you do not choose anything it will not let you submit.