# checkValidity / reportVality not working for values set via code

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML5 `checkValidity()` / `reportValidity()` methods don't seem to work if values are set via JavaScript.

Consider this example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LocatiM/q7yrzvah/1/)):

```
<input id="text-field" maxlength="3" placeholder="Max len: 3 chars" />
<button id="set-field-value">Set</button>
<button id="check-valid">Is valid?</button>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var textField = document.getElementById('text-field');
    document.getElementById('set-field-value').onclick = function() {
        textField.value = 'This is a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text';
    };
    document.getElementById('check-valid').onclick = function() {
        window.alert(textField.checkValidity());
    };
};
</script>
```

If you click the `Set` button, the value of the input field is set to an invalid value (it's length is greater that 3 characters), but the `checkValidity()` method still says that the input is valid (checked on Chrome, Edge and Firefox).

Why? Is there a way to determine is the field is valid even if its value is set via code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triggering HTML5 Form Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation)

Comment: @A. Meshu what exactly should answer this specific issue of HTML5 validation not working as expected?

Comment: If you read this thread (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48267035/6525081) you'll see that you need to check the form and not the input itself. I encounter it after i wrote my answer, but i thought that this hold the answer to your question. As both of us can see - i was wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the form valid not the input. BUT it seems that the `maxLength` attribute is not something that trigger validation at all...

If you want to check length of input text you can do that with this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var textField = document.getElementById('text-field');
  document.getElementById('set-field-value').onclick = function() { textField.value = 'ab'; };
  document.getElementById('check-valid').onclick = function() {
    if (textField.value && // if exist AND
      textField.value.length > 2 && // if value have 3 charecter at least
      textField.value.trim().length > 2 // if value is not just spaces 
    ) {alert ('input OK');} // alert that input ok
    else { alert('please insert at least 3 charecters');} // else alert error
  };
};
```

```html
<form id="formCheck">
  <input type="text" id="text-field" min="3" />
  <button type="button" id="set-field-value">Set</button>
  <button type="button" id="check-valid">Is valid?</button>
</form>
```

The `checkValidity()` method works as expected on this example (using input number and `min` attribute) though:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var theForm =  document.getElementById('formCheck');
  var numberField = document.getElementById('number-field');
  document.getElementById('set-field-value').onclick = function() { numberField.value = '2'; };
  document.getElementById('check-valid').onclick = function() {
    window.alert(theForm.checkValidity());
  };
};
```

```html
<form id="formCheck">
<input type="number" id="number-field" min="3" />
<button type="button" id="set-field-value">Set</button>
<button type="button" id="check-valid">Is valid?</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this a while. It seems that you're at least missing `<form>` wrapping the input + button content.

But still, even if I tried to set input field `required`, still the **ValidityObject** won't notice that length is exceeded.

As a semi-workaround, I came with an idea of using `pattern` property:

```
<input id='textfield' pattern='\S{0,3}'>
```

(= *\S* stands for 'all characters except spaces')

This at least will prevent for content beyond three characters. In addition, you can have a `setCustomValidity` message for invalid cases.

See working example at: https://codepen.io/zvona/pen/rNavqxP?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few things that led me to understand that checkValidity does not check the value itself.

When I click on #check-validity I get :

```
textField.validity.tooLong // false
textField.validity.valid // true
textField.value // This is a very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text
```

When I type myself in the input, my browser does not let me type more than 3 characters.

> Why?

Precisely I don't know, but there is this awesome article on [constraint validation](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) that is worth having a look.

> Is there a way to determine is the field is valid even if its value is
>   set via code?

textField.value returns your string, you can then access it's length. In this context, I would have anyway prefered this way.

```
const tooLong = textField.value.length > 3;
if (tooLong) window.alert('Something');
```

I hope it helps.