# Display pattern error without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, design-patterns

i have a form that i have put on couple pages, I have a 'Next' button wich is displaying the next page, and, when on last page turns to a submit button
But I want my form to display the pattern errors of my text input before going to nextpage.
So how can I trigger this message with javascript ?
I prefer not using JQuery, but if there is no other solution i'll take it :)

[This is the pattern/empty-field error i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1keV.png)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation)

Comment: Thanks it helped me even if it's not exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should caught the submit event, do event.preventDefault(), to prevent default forn submitting, and then do your validation.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution !