# Adding a validation for input type, so the user is not allowed to enter anything other than numbers with a min and max value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do this in HTML for now where I have a input field of `type=number` where I don't want the user to be able to type decimal values/special characters/alphabets at all. I also want the `min=30` and `max=300`so if a user types `29` and clicks else where, the value in the field should change to the `min` which is `30`. If the user types in a value greater than `300` and clicks elsewhere, then I want the value to change to `300` which is the max. I don't want to wait for the user to wait for them to click on a form button. This is what I have so far, where the error is that, the user can still type decimal, and type any value lower than 30. Very new to html/js. Feel free to help me with js implementation if you think that is easier.

```
<input type="number" min="30" max="300" step="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value=value.replace(/\D+/g, ''))" id="seconds" name="seconds" value="30">
```

Comment: `.reportValidity()` in the `oninput` should/could work -> [Manually Triggering Form Validation using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/manually-triggering-form-validation-using-jquery)

Comment: @Andreas that's javascript, right? could you show me how exactly? i couldn't understand much from the link.

Comment: @Andreas again, I don't want to wait for the button to be clicked on for the input to be validated.

Comment: _"that's javascript, right?"_ - Like the stuff in your `oninput` attribute. _"I don't want to wait for the button to be clicked"_ hence I've written _"in the `oninput`"_, just like you do right now.

Comment: @Andreas understood! could you show me how to implement it with my case? I really couldn't understand from the online documentation. i'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

<html>

```
<script>

    function change(){

        var inp  = document.getElementById("box").value;
        
            inp = Math.floor(inp);  
            if(inp<30){

            document.getElementById("box").value = 30;

        }

            else if(inp>300){

            document.getElementById("box").value = 300;

        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("box").value = inp;
        }
    }

                

</script>
```

<BODY>

```
<input type= "number" onmouseout = "change()" id ="box"/>
```

</BODY>

</HTML>

this java script should do
use "**onmouseout**".

Comment: what do you mean by use "onmouseout"? how would I implement that? can you show me?

Comment: onmouseout is an used to check if mouse is over an element

Comment: just use that *script's* function and its Java Script inside it and add it in header section. Then add *onmouseout* in place of your *onclick* attribute.

Comment: if you don't get it just copy change function from here. Paste it in your header's script tag. Do the same for input tag. don't copy anything else. Then your problem should be solved.