# Submit form without submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Confusing title, I know. I'll try to word this as best as I can.

---

**What I have**

A large form made up of multiple sections. Only one section is visible at one time, and clicking the Continue button just displays the next part of the form using javascript. Some inputs contain the `type='email'` attribute.

[image]

---

***What I want to happen***

When the user clicks a Continue button, I want the browser to think the form is being submitted so it does its checks on the `type='email'` inputs and displays a message if the input is not valid, just like this.
[image]

But I **do not** want it to submit the form when the *Continue* button is clicked.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to add that I also need the form to submit at the end. So I cannot use the `onsubmit='return false'` approach.

---

***What currently happens***

At the moment, the browser validation activates when I click the final Submit button (because the form is actually being submitted). But this is too late because the form sections are all closed now, and users will not be able to see which input needs attention.

Comment: Title is... Well, it is somewhat strange.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548612/triggering-html5-form-validation

Comment: trigger your validation `onblur` of `input`

Comment: If you are going to use `javascript` on your page, you might as well use `jquery` in conjunction with the `jquery validation plugin`.  It will take more work than simply using html attributes to enforce validation but it will take much less work than writing the `javascript` to validate the page yourself. Plus, it gives you a lot more control of when validation occurs and what happens when validation occurs.

Comment: why don't you just have your continue button check validity of inputs and then progress to next page.

Comment: do you want to perform client side validation or server side validation? if server side then submit your form as a target to an iframe

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002230/trigger-standard-html5-validation-form-without-using-submit-button

Comment: @elitechief21 I'm using javascript for validation anyway, but I still want to keep the html5 attribute for the sake of semantic code and also so the keyboard layout changes on some devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add form and submit button attributes:

```
<form onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="email" /> <!-- this will validate! -->
    <button type="submit" onClick="showNextForm();">Continue</button>
</form>
```

No code was shown by you, so I can't optimize yours appropriately, but this is essentially what you need to do to your `<form>` and `<button>`.

The form will validate, but will not submit!

Comment: you forgot the equals `<form onSubmit="return false;">`

Comment: Why the downvote? This works since the OP is using HTML5 element type=email.

Comment: I hate it when people downvote but give no explanation, stackoverflow is a place to improve your contributions, which you cannot do if idiots go around downvoting answers without first giving constructive criticism.

Comment: @StaticVoid Unfortunately this will not work as I still need to submit the form at the end.

Comment: When you get to the end, you can .serialize the form and post it using jquery.

Comment: Why not use `<input type="submit" onclick="showNextForm()">`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach you can use.

```
$(function(){
    $('#continue').click(function(e){
        if(!$('#email')[0].checkValidity()){
            $('#form').find(':submit').click();
        }
        else {
            //Open next section
            alert('Opening next section');
        }
    });
});
```

Working jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/5bzNx/3/

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
<form onsubmit="return yourJSCheckFunction();">
```

Comment: Would you like to add a explanation to your code? Code answers are alright but explanations are gold

Comment: This would not work in my situation as I still need to submit the form at the end.

Comment: You can submit with the XMLHttpRequest object in javascript [link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)