# Want html pattern attribute work without hitting a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, submit-button

I am working on validation and put a html pattern attribute and want to see the error message without hitting a save/submit button. When I click outside the field then it should be validate with my pattern condition.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Extra Credit Days<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_credit_days" name="" 
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[WQYDM])(?=.*[WQYDM]).{1,3}"title="Enter in specified 
format">
</div> </div>
```

What will be the JQuery or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate on blur the regex. Do some things if bad string given

```js
$("input[pattern]").blur(function(){
  var elem = $(this);
  
  var pattern = new RegExp(elem.attr("pattern"));
  if (pattern.test(elem.val())) {
     alert('okay');
  } else {
    alert('bad');
     //disable form submit
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="form-group">
<label>Extra Credit Days<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_credit_days" name="" 
pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[WQYDM])(?=.*[WQYDM]).{1,3}"title="Enter in specified 
format">
</div> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach that works for me on Chrome:

- Create a hidden submit button.
- Listen for the `focusout` event on the `input` field.
- Trigger `click` on the hidden submit button.

This should trigger HTML5 validation whenever the field loses focus (clicking outside of the field or tabbing out of it).

Snippet:

```js
let input = document.getElementById("txt_credit_days");
let inputButton = document.getElementById("inputButton");

input.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
  inputButton.click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Extra Credit Days<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <form id="form">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txt_credit_days" name="" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[WQYDM])(?=.*[WQYDM]).{1,3}" title="Enter in specified 
format">
      <input type="submit" class="hide" id="inputButton" style="visibility:hidden;">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you don't require the browser-based validation alert (i.e., you'd rather show your own alert dialog or some other message notifying the user that validation failed), then you could just use the `checkValidity()` method on the input element.

Comment: but i don't want to hit any button. when i clicked on screen or outside that field then it will be validate on that condition.

Comment: @Aditya You don't have to hit any button. It's simulated. Click "Run code snippet", enter some data in the field, then click out of it to see what I mean.

Comment: Yeah!! Thank you Its Working .

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688122/html5-form-validation-void-form-action-and-execute-jquery-when-all-html5-form-e).
You can manualy trigger submit with javascript and preventDefault on change event of input tho.